# Using python, how to save a valid audio file from bytes?

Tags: python-3.x, file, speech-recognition, audio-recording

I am working with speech recognition library in Python and trying to save an audio file after submiting to the API that recognize it. So, my problem comes when I want to save that audio to a file.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
mic = sr.Microphone()

print('Recording...')
with mic as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)

with open("audio_file.wav", "wb") as file:
    file.write(audio.frame_data)
```

The audio_file.wav have a size approximately of 210kb(about 4 or 5 seconds recording)

when I try to reproduce the audio file.wav, the player throws an error saying that **can not play the audio**... due to a codec problem.

My question are:
am I missing save a headers or something like that?
Is there another way to saves audio bytes into a file?

**Edit**
My answer is in this question [Wav file from microphone on Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46738569/wav-file-from-microphone-on-python)

Comment: assuming `audio.frame_data` is a byte-like structure, this code should work, although a safer and more idiomatic way is to use context manager:  `with open("audio_file.wav", "wb") as file: file.write(audio.frame_data)`, since it will make sure that the file is closed even if something happens during the `write` operation. Additionally you may add `file.flush()` after `write` to make sure that the output is flushed to disk.

Comment: @TarasTsugrii. The audio.frame_data is a ```<class 'bytes'>``` type. I check with the safe mode that you suggest and keep getting the same result. Thanks any way.

Comment: You still didn't explain what the problem is, it should create a file just fine.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I edited the question to make it more simple. I hope that in this way it is easier to understand.

Comment: You can open this headerless file in audacity.

Comment: In case you need to save it with a header you can use wave module.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binary string to wav file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33245371/binary-string-to-wav-file)

Comment: I just find the answer  in another question [Wav file from microphone on Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46738569/wav-file-from-microphone-on-python)

Answer (score 4):

Change `audio.frame_data` to `audio.get_wav_data()`.